# S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified: error with flutter_local_notification

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent, flutter-local-notification

I am working on a Flutter Application and have implemented **Firebase Cloud Messaging**, to receive messages sent from the server. I am using the **flutter_local_notifications** package.
I referred- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/example for notifications and [https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#foreground-messages:~:text=found%20here.-,Message%20types,-%23](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#foreground-messages:%7E:text=found%20here.-,Message%20types,-%23) for Cloud messaging.
In my **main.dart-**

```
Future<void> _messageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('background message ${message.notification!.body}');
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await setupFlutterNotifications();
  showFlutterNotification(message);
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

/// Create a [AndroidNotificationChannel] for heads up notifications
late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;

bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false;

Future<void> setupFlutterNotifications() async {
  if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized) {
    return;
  }
  channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    // 'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  /// Create an Android Notification Channel.
  ///
  /// We use this channel in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to override the
  /// default FCM channel to enable heads up notifications.
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
  /// heads up notifications.
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = true;
}

void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          // channel.description,
          icon: 'launch_background',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
_configureForegroundMessaging(){
   FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    log('new notificaiton: ${message.data}');
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android!;

    // If `onMessage` is triggered with a notification, construct our own
    // local notification to show to users using the created channel.
    if (notification != null && android != null) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              // channel.description,
              icon: android.smallIcon,
              // other properties...
            ),
          ));
    }
  });
}
/// Initialize the [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin] package.
late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  if (!kIsWeb) {
    await setupFlutterNotifications();
  }
  _configureForegroundMessaging();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  await _initializePrefs();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml-**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.blog_app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:label="blog_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When a notification is sent, the app crashes and I get the following error-

```
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.blog_app: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:465)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:451)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:415)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:176)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:820)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1109)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:996)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(25254):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
D/AndroidRuntime(25254): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(25254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(25254): Process: com.example.blog_app, PID: 25254
E/AndroidRuntime(25254): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.blog_app.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.blog_app.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~JLhSAfO9gLJElJK0cBbFwA==/com.example.blog_app-WTmVE1_SbB9GDNb1kBivcQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~JLhSAfO9gLJElJK0cBbFwA==/com.example.blog_app-WTmVE1_SbB9GDNb1kBivcQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~JLhSAfO9gLJElJK0cBbFwA==/com.example.blog_app-WTmVE1_SbB9GDNb1kBivcQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4953)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2300)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.blog_app.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~JLhSAfO9gLJElJK0cBbFwA==/com.example.blog_app-WTmVE1_SbB9GDNb1kBivcQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~JLhSAfO9gLJElJK0cBbFwA==/com.example.blog_app-WTmVE1_SbB9GDNb1kBivcQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~JLhSAfO9gLJElJK0cBbFwA==/com.example.blog_app-WTmVE1_SbB9GDNb1kBivcQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:129)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:75)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4922)
E/AndroidRuntime(25254):    ... 9 more
I/Process (25254): Sending signal. PID: 25254 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

**After this error, the notification appears in the notification bar in the phone (when the app is killed or is in background) and does not appear at all when the app is in foreground (although I have configured for it to appear.)**
I searched for the problem but did not find anything related to this issue in Flutter.
Please help me resolve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Update your **flutter_local_notifications** package in my case it was solved with version:

```
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.5.2
```

Comment: I updated the version to the latest version right now, which is 13.0.0. Still I am getting the error when notification is sent. The app crashes with the error message I have now specified.

Comment: same error here with version 13.0.0